# How important is magic find?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm level 55 and I have a measly 22% increase in Magic Find, should I have more? Does it even matter? I'm not getting as many rares as I'd expect to get, not even that many blues, and I haven't seen a good item since that level 21 blade I found a long... loooong time ago.

What am I doing wrong if I want more rares, and good ones at that?

Comment: I think this question is poorly worded, you may want to reword to avoid closing.  I think what you are really shooting for is "how do I most effectively acquire magic items", possibly even more specifically "rares" or "legendaries".  I'll take a stab with that in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an answerable question here that doesn't overlap existing MF questions. IMHO the only real answer to "how important is MF? is "How much do you want magic items?"

Comment: Does magic find affect the chance to being able to login to Diablo 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you reach max level you will certainly be grinding act 1 inferno for awhile; both to boost your own abilities via the odd lucky find and to get enough gold to get the elite items necessary to progress past act 1.

On these runs, you'll want to have as much MF as possible without sacrificing your ability to kill and avoid being killed, as more MF translates into more gold AND more rares/legendary, so both your "lucky find" ratio as well as your gold output will improve.

As such, ignore what EBongo just said and work on getting MF when you hit max level.

Answer (score 2):

Magic Find improves the chances that you will find magic/rare/set/legendary items. It also affects the number of affixes that a rare item will get. It does not affect the item level of the loot that is dropped, which affixes the item gets, or the random values associated with those affixes. It does not affect gems or potions things or other types of non-equippable items. It does not affect the amount of items that you find (only their quality).

Here's a recap of how magic find works.

- Magic Find has always been one of the most popular item attributes in Diablo. Magic find helps increase the probability that a higher quality item will drop from monsters.
- Magic Find helps increase the likelihood of Magic, Rare, Set and Legendary items dropping.
  The Magic Find attribute can be found on any items that are high enough to support the affixes.
- Magic Find is based on a percentile increase.
- You get 20% of the MF found on your follower.
- When played cooperatively items drop separately for each player. This means each player sees their own loot and not loot that has dropped for the other people in the group. When picked up and dropped on the ground or traded the items obviously become visible to the other players as well.
- When playing in a group, the total Magic Find of the group will be divided equally among each player. Here is an example given by Blizzard: "The group consists of four players. In total, their stats are 50% MF, +20% GF and 10% XP, each of these players will have a 12.5% ​​MF, 5% GF and 2.5% XP being in such a group."
- Players will find stacking Magic Find gear more difficult than Diablo II due to the sacrifice of other important attributes.
- Topaz gems will add Magic Find when socketed into a Helmet.
- There is no cap on how much Magic Find you can have.

Keep in mind that your chance of getting a certain item type is multiplied by your increased magic find. For example, if you have +100% magic find, then you won't find magic items all the time. Instead, if a legendary has a 0.1% chance to drop off of this particular monster, then it will instead have a 0.2% chance to drop (an extra 100% of it's base chance).

Comment: Good answer. One point of clarification: there is no cap on MF, but there *is* a limit in how much you'll be able to equip, based off of the range of values available.  The practical maximum (until itemization gets changed) appears to be [about 446%](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68969/8096) (including 5 stacks of NV + Fortune Shrine).

Answer (score 0):

Applying some interpretation to your question, I would say that by far the most important way to find rares and legendaries is the Auction House.  Once you are familiar with the stats that matter to your class, you can easily search for low buyout items that are typically way better than what you will find via trial and error searching.  I'm still in the mid levels, so maybe the going gets tough near 60, but so far I have found various items that are ***a steal***.

Beyond that, it doesn't make much sense to use magic find for [get items for crafting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66906/is-it-viable-to-invest-in-gold-find-instead-of-magic-find-for-getting-crafting-m) since while certainly helps your luck, trash items on the AH are also in high supply.... and why are you crafting in the first place when you can buy such awesome stuff for cheap anyway?

[Others suggest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66752/is-it-worth-investing-in-magic-find-early-on-in-diablo-3-to-build-up-your-piggy) that magic find may be used to build up your cashflow early on, but I haven't found that to be a problem - and... I've made way better money, ***at the Auction House***.

Comment: I don't know where you got "crafting" from my question, but now that you've mentioned it, does it make no sense to level up the crafters?

Comment: I was referencing other reasons why magic find might be important.  Generally speaking, it is not worthwhile to level crafting right now - to get gear.  I do believe there are some achievements associated with it, and of course there is The Staff of Herding.

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to find rares is grinding to lvl 60 and then making some type of boss runs. However, before defeating the boss in the boss run, you should make sure to go and kill 5 packs of unique/champion monsters. Killing 5 champion/elite packs when you are lvl 60 will give 5 stacks of nephalem valour, which substantially increases your gold and magic find. Also, the 5 nephalem valour stacks will make some quest story line bosses drop additional loot. So if you are killing e.g. diablo with 5 nephalem valour stacks, you seem to be guaranteed to always get rare items.